# OpenCover CommandLine doesn't give back right coverage

Tags: unit-testing, code-coverage, opencover

I am trying to get the code coverage of an project i am working on with OpenCover. Now when I use the OpenCoverUI tool for VS2013 it generates the code coverage perfectly (about 60%). However I now want to write a script that will make the use of OpenCoverUI obsolete (because i want to be able to preform this on any VS). However when i run my script as below I now get a code coverage of only 2% I assume I am doing something wrong in my script but for the life of me i do not know what

My script is as folows

```
"C:\Users\ldam\Documents\Git\CentralFinal\packages\OpenCover.4.6.519\tools\OpenCover.Console.exe" -register:user -target:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\mstest.exe" -targetargs:"/testcontainer:\"C:\Users\ldam\Documents\Git\CentralFinal\CentralStationApi.Tests\bin\Debug\CentralStationApi.dll\" /resultsfile:C:\Users\ldam\Documents\CentralStationApi.trx" -filter:"+[CentralStationApi*]*" -mergebyhash  -output:"C:\Users\ldam\Documents\CentralStationApi.xml"
cd C:\Users\ldam\Documents\Git\CentralFinal\packages\ReportGenerator.2.4.4.0\tools
ReportGenerator.exe "-reports:C:\Users\ldam\Documents\CentralStationApi.xml" "-targetdir:C:\Users\ldam\Test\fifth"
pause
```

My question is how do I get OpenCover to correctly analyse the code coverage like it does with the OpenCoverUI

Answer (score 0):

You might have to look at where your .NET entry point is.
http://learningbytesting.mathume.com/2016/04/opencover-and-fitnessefitsharp.html